# JS script blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In a personal project I am using html to "host" a js application (a basic calculator), after some updates the js script doesn't  load... I've checked the console and it gives me this error:

`The resource from “http://127.0.0.1:5500/bhaskara/assets/js/bhaskara.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).`

I found some related questions about this and did some tests but nothing worked.

**1 Test**: I put a Type tag in the  (DID NOT WORK)

*Before:*

```
<script src="../bhaskara/assets/js/bhaskara.js"></script>
```

*After*

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../bhaskara/assets/js/bhaskara.js"></script>
```

**2 Test**: Change the  location (DID NOT WORK)

*Before:*

```
<body>

<tags>
<tags>

<script src="../bhaskara/assets/js/bhaskara.js"></script>

</body>
```

*After*

```
<head>

<script src="../bhaskara/assets/js/bhaskara.js"></script>

</head>
```

I am really out of Ideas on how to fix this....

Comment: This is a problem on the server that you are hosting the javascript file with on port 5500. It returns the mime type header "text/html" along with your javascript file. Instead it should return the "text/javascript" header. What server software are you using?

Comment: I am using the Live Server (VS CODE).

Comment: Ah, in that case you might be dealing with the same problem that this user has reported: https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/issues/576

Comment: Solved! Just for the record it was not the Vs live code but the browser I was using... Apparently I running it in Chrome solves the issue... (Mozilla Firefox Developer Edition does not like Js LOL.